# <DIV> with three background images

Tags: css

I need to place three different background images inside a div. At the top I want blue.png, then in the middle yellow.png (with repeat-y), and finally, red.png at the bottom.

[image: Example]

So far, I have this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nwUPU/1437/. My problem is that yellow.png covers both blue.png and red.png. What am I doing wrong, please?

**This example is used in responsive design. I do not know the width and height of the images.**

```
.colors {
  width:600px;
  height:600px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background: url("http://s9.postimg.org/47v6naitr/blue.png") center top no-repeat, url("http://s1.postimg.org/fgv3q86i7/red.png") center bottom no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
.colors:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url("http://s24.postimg.org/hyhdhfg51/yellow.png") center top repeat-y;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Do the images have a fixed height and width or is it variable?

Comment: The example is used in responsive design. I do not know the witdh and height of the images.

Comment: Would [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nwUPU/1438/) help?

Comment: Harry, it helps. Can you please paste your code here so I can make it the accepted answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to add multiple backgrounds to the same element by providing them as coma separated values to the `background` property. Each background image that is provided will be added as a layer and will be stacked one on top of another (also depending on the `background-position`).

The key things to note here are:

- When multiple backgrounds are applied to the same element, the first one is the top-most layer and the one provided last is the lower-most layer. Since we need the yellow to be sort of below the red and blue, it should be provided as the last value.
- To position the blue and red images at their respective positions, `background-position` should be set appropriately. Since blue should be the first from top, it should be positioned at `0% 0%` and since the red needs to be last from top, it should be positioned at `100% 100%`.

```css
.colors {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  background: url("http://s9.postimg.org/47v6naitr/blue.png") center top no-repeat,
              url("http://s1.postimg.org/fgv3q86i7/red.png") center bottom no-repeat,
              url("http://s24.postimg.org/hyhdhfg51/yellow.png") center top repeat-y;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: 0% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors"></div>
```

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: Why would it be non-cross-browser? Multiple background images are pretty well supported. Have a look at [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds) chart. I personally don't care about IE8 as MS themselves are dropping support for it in Jan 16.

Comment: We'll, it's OK if you don't need ie8 support

Comment: If anybody is still on IE8, I would recommend them to upgrade immediately for their own good. Sticking on to a product which is not going to be supported for much longer by its developers is no good.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Probably 80% of all CSS answers are not supported by ie8

Answer (score 2):

Possibly add three divs inside your first. each with their own .png?

```
<div>
    <div id="blue" style="z-index: 1;"><img src="blue.png"></div>
    <div id="yellow"style="z-index: 2;"><img src="yellow.png"></div>
    <div id="red" style="z-index: 1;"><img src="red.png"></div>
</div>
```